# Why do Injecting bean still needs code change?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring and I know the basic principles of DI . What I am unable to understand is we still need to make code change in the Parent class if we wish to change the bean type .

For eg in below code
We need to specify Qualifier("bike") in Service class.So tomorrow i need to change this to new implm in Service class like Qualifier("car"). Similarly if there is truck I need to create new class that extends vehicle and use in Service as Qualifier("truck"). I still need to go the class and change this 1 line of code.Change is still inevitable.What benefit am I actually getting doing this
:

```
    public interface Vehicle {
         public void start();
         public void stop();
    }

    @Component(value="car")
    public class Car implements Vehicle {
     @Override
     public void start() {
           System.out.println("Car started");
     }

     @Override
     public void stop() {
           System.out.println("Car stopped");
     }
 }

@Component(value="bike")
public class Bike implements Vehicle {

     @Override
     public void start() {
          System.out.println("Bike started");
     }

     @Override
     public void stop() {
          System.out.println("Bike stopped");
     }
}



@Component
public class VehicleService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("bike")
    private Vehicle vehicle;

    public void service() {
         vehicle.start();
         vehicle.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because spring doesn't know when you say you need an instance of vehicle weather to give you a Bike or Car, @Qualifier helps to inform spring that you require a specific one.

If you are not concerned with which one you want in the VehicleService, then you can
You can use the [@Primary](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) to mark one of them as primary one so spring can resolve the conflict

Or, have Vehicle as a list in the VehicleService and pick the appropriate needed one from the list, you can use the [@Order](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html?is-external=true) anotation to order the values in the list. You can use the @PostConstruct anotation to write the logic of which one of the values to pick up.